# Is there a zcat equivalent for ansible?

Tags: ansible

Is there a nicer way of doing `zcat` in ansible than invoking `shell`?

```
- name: "Unpack the local config"
  shell: "zcat /proc/config.gz > /usr/src/linux/.config"
  args:
    creates: "/usr/src/linux/.config"
```

Comment: If you've a recent ansible, 2.2+, you could probably use [`unarchive`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/unarchive_module.html) with `remote_src: yes`. I don't have access to test just now.

Comment: @jscott I tried that earlier but it seems like unarchive dest is implied to be a directory where the files get unpacked too. It doesn't let me unpack a blob into a file. As far as my attempts went at least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the future there might be an `uncompress` module, but today no:

https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/issues/3241#issuecomment-240991265

> The unarchive module only supports archives, not compressed files. The documentation was improved to make that more clear. We anticipate a new pure-python uncompress module that will support compressed files as well as archives, which would then deprecate the unarchive module.